# Error in concatenation and one more error

Tags: python, list, concatenation

I'm trying to import a csv file and then output the continuous series from the file into a new csv file
the contents of the file are like
1
5
6
7
8
and so on
here for example the output would be ['1,1','5,5','6,8']

The error i'm getting is

```
>>> gaps = [[s, e] for s, e in zip(nums, nums[1:]) if s+1 < e]
TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "int") to str
```

Also for some reason after I do `str1 = str1.replace(i, '')`
it turns `str1` into

```
['2855']'2856']'3250']'3251']'3252']'3253']'3254']'3255']'3256']'3257']'3258']'3259']'3260']'3261']'3262']'3263']'3264']'3265']'3278']'3279']'3280']'3281']'3299']'3312']'3314']'3331']'3332']'3333']'3334']'3405']'3406']'3407']'3408']'3500']'4849']'4850']'5567']'5568']'5569']'6000']
2856]3250]3251]3252]3253]3254]3255]3256]3257]3258]3259]3260]3261]3262]3263]3264]3265]3278]3279]3280]3281]3299]3312]3314]3331]3332]3333]3334]3405]3406]3407]3408]3500]4849]4850]5567]5568]5569]6000]
```

intead of giving just

`2856]3250]3251]3252]3253]3254]3255]3256]3257]3258]3259]3260]3261]3262]3263]3264]3265]3278]3279]3280]3281]3299]3312]3314]3331]3332]3333]3334]3405]3406]3407]3408]3500]4849]4850]5567]5568]5569]6000]`

The code:

```
   with open('Book1.csv', newline='') as f:
       reader = csv.reader(f)
       data = list(reader)
       str1 = ''.join(str(e) for e in data)
       bad_chars = ["[","'"]
   for i in bad_chars :
       str1 = str1.replace(i, '')
       str1.split("]",-1)
   x = list((str1.split("]")))
   def ranges(nums):
       nums = sorted(set(nums))
       gaps = [[s, e] for s, e in zip(nums, nums[1:]) if s+1 < e]
       edges = iter(nums[:1] + sum(gaps, []) + nums[-1:])
       return list(zip(edges, edges))
   print(ranges(x))
```

Comment: So, you are saying that the input is a string "[['123'], ['456']]", and you want it to become [123, 456], a list of integers, right?

Comment: Actually what i'm trying to do is first retrieve data from a csv file then see the start and of all the x+1 series,     for example if the input is [1,2,3,5,8,9] (in the csv file the input has no commas in between every value is in a new line)     so for this case the output would be [1,3,5,5,8,9] i.e it will print the start and and ending number of all the x+1 series the erros i'm facing are    1. when i try to replace ] with an empty space  for some reason i start duplicate of the list i.e. the list contains all the values two times like this ↆ (str1 = str1.replace(i,''))

Comment: ["'2855'", "'2856'", "'3250'", "'3251'", "'3252'", "'3253'", "'3254'", "'3255'", "'3256'", "'3257'", "'3258'", "'3259'", "'3260'", "'3261'", "'3262'", "'3263'", "'3264'", "'3265'", "'3278'", "'3279'", "'3280'", "'3281'", "'3299'", "'3312'", "'3314'", "'3331'", "'3332'", '']['2855', '2856', '3250', '3251', '3252', '3253', '3254', '3255', '3256', '3257', '3258', '3259', '3260', '3261', '3262', '3263', '3264', '3265', '3278', '3279', '3280', '3281', '3299', '3312', '3314', '3331', '3332', '']

Comment: Also the second problem i'm facing is that it shows the error can only concatenate str (not "int") to str on the line  gaps = [[s, e] for s, e in zip(nums, nums[1:]) if s+1 < e]             i understand that it is happening cause you can't concatenate two different types i.e. string with integers but i'm not abe to fix it

Comment: Can you provide a sample of the csv file? I don't get it. If your csv file has integers in it, on separate lines, then how come are you getting "[" and "," in your input?

Comment: https://1drv.ms/u/s!AmxKQ-CimfU9gYUXvyQ080VxHEDTvA?e=k6RzzX.                                      link to file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
def ranges(nums):
       nums = sorted(set(nums))
       gaps = [[s, e] for s, e in zip(nums, nums[1:]) if s+1 < e]
       edges = iter(nums[:1] + sum(gaps, []) + nums[-1:])
       return list(zip(edges, edges))


data = []
with open('Book1.csv', newline='') as f:
       reader = csv.reader(f)
       for i in reader:
           data.append(int(i[0]))
       
   
print(ranges(data))
```

The problem with your code was you were making the code more complex and the task redundant by joining lists of strings to a big string, and then removing the bad chars from it. Instead you could just add the integer parts of separate lists beforehand and saved the time, like I did.

Also, the code in `ranges` function was giving error because you were trying to add string `s` to `1`, which is an integer. What you didn't realise then that the `x` list still contained string types.